# Can a button on a card within MS Teams chat launch a TaskModule w/ compose capabilities?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

My goal to create a looping process like this:

- A user clicks button in a card in the chat launching a task module
- A user submits task module inserting card in chat
- Another user starts process over with that card

---

The sample code below allows the following flow, **which breaks down at 4**:

1. User A select a Messaging Extension action –`composeExtension/fetchTask` - app launches a task module
2. User A submits task module - `composeExtension/submitAction` - app adds card to compose box of chat
3. User B selects button of card in chat - `task/fetch` - app launches task module
4. User B submits task module - `task/submit` - app is **unable to add card** since this is not a Messaging Extension handler

Note that steps 1 & 2 can be replaced by, for example, a link unfurl.

**What is the lowest friction way to allow a user at step 4 to submit a card back to the compose box / chat?** Ideally this doesn't require the user to specifically authorize the app in the specific conversation; the user's action shows their intent.

```
class SimpleTeamsBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {

  // Handle 'composeExtension/fetchTask'
  handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask = async (
    context: TurnContext,
    taskModuleRequest: TaskModuleRequest
  ): Promise<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> =>
    Promise.resolve({
      task: {
        type: "continue",
        value: {
          card: getTaskModuleCard(),
          title: "Task Module",
        },
      },
    });

  // Handle 'composeExtension/submitAction'
  handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction = async (
    context: TurnContext,
    taskModuleRequest: TaskModuleRequest
  ): Promise<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> =>
    Promise.resolve({
      composeExtension: {
        attachmentLayout: "list",
        type: "result",
        attachments: [getChatCard()],
      },
    });

  // Handle 'task/fetch'
  handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch = async (
    context: TurnContext,
    taskModuleRequest: TaskModuleRequest
  ): Promise<TaskModuleResponse> =>
    Promise.resolve({
      task: {
        type: "continue",
        value: {
          card: getTaskModuleCard(),
          title: "Task Module",
        },
      },
    });

  // Handle 'task/submit'
  handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit = async (
    context: TurnContext,
    taskModuleRequest: TaskModuleRequest
  ): Promise<TaskModuleResponse> =>
    Promise.resolve({ task: { type: "message", value: "Thanks!" } });

  // Link Unfurling.
  handleTeamsAppBasedLinkQuery = async (
    context: TurnContext,
    query: AppBasedLinkQuery
  ): Promise<MessagingExtensionResponse> =>
    Promise.resolve({
      composeExtension: {
        attachmentLayout: "list",
        type: "result",
        attachments: [getChatCard()],
      },
    });
}

const getChatCard = () =>
  CardFactory.heroCard(
    "Title",
    "Subtitle",
    [],
    [
      {
        type: "invoke",
        title: "Launch",
        value: {
          type: "task/fetch",
          data: {},
        },
      },
    ]
  );

const getTaskModuleCard = () =>
  CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
    type: "AdaptiveCard",
    actions: [
      {
        type: "Action.Submit",
        title: "Submit",
      },
    ],
    $schema: "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    version: "1.4",
  });
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: Thanks @Sayali-MSFT - rewritten and added code. Let me know if there is anything I can clarify!

Comment: Looks like It is not possible.We can directly send a card into chat. but cannot hold in compose area.
 instead of having it in compose area is it okay to send a card in chat?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I think that would work, assuming it can target the channel which contains the card with which the user originally interacted.  How would that work?